# Error when installing qiimer package for R

Tags: r, failed-installation, qiime, biom

I tried to install `qiimer` package for R (3.6.2) from CRAN under Win10, but I failed. Then I tried to install it locally from ‘qiimer_0.9.4.tar.gz’, and failed, neither.

I do not understand why CRAN does not afford this package anymore. I wonder how can I install it on my PC? Because I need it for another package `Tax4Fun`.

The following are the command I tried,

(1) Installation from CRAN.

```
install.packages("qiimer")
```

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘qiimer’ is not available (for R version 3.6.2)

(2) Installation locally.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/User/Downloads/qiimer_0.9.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

> ERROR: dependency 'pheatmap' is not available for package 'qiimer'
>   removing 'C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/qiimer'
>   Warning in install.packages :
>   installation of package ‘C:/Users/User/Downloads/qiimer_0.9.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Thank you very much!

Zhang

Comment: *"I do not understand why CRAN does not afford this package anymore."* CRAN states that "check problems were not corrected in time". Seeing that the last update to `qiime` was in 2015 my feeling is that the package is (one of the many) R package zombies. Perhaps you can contact the original package author? Alternatively, have you seen [`qiime2`](https://github.com/qiime2/qiime2).

Comment: If you *must* install the CRAN-deprecated `qiime` version, try installing `pheatmap` first with `install.packages("pheatmap")`; then re-install the gzip'ed `qiimer` tar ball.